# Do we ever find out what Ike did to have his law license revoked?

Tags: john-grisham, theodore-boone

In *Theodore Boone*, Ike Boone gets his license to practice law revoked. Do we ever find out why? Is this mentioned in *The Activist*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems there's no textual evidence as to why his license was revoked.

The closest thing we have is this, from *The Accused*:

> "Listen to me, Theo. A long time ago, I was a successful lawyer in Strattenburg, had an office just down the hall from your mother, had lots of clients, and life was good. **Then the cops showed up and started asking questions. I didn't have all the answers. They came back with more questions, then more.** I couldn't believe what was happening and I slowly realized I was headed for trouble, but I couldn't stop it. Once the criminal justice system starts moving against you, it's hard to stop.

(emphasis mine)

This seems to hint at some form of legal malpractice, but we don't know for sure.

Comment: Yes, but it seems like he *didn't* actually do anything according to that...

Comment: @Mithrandir He obviously must have done something that attracted the attention of the police. Grisham is just annoyingly vague at that portion, so I'm guessing the reason Ike no longer has his license is fully intended to be a mystery.

Comment: @fi12 It could be a plot point in a future book.

Comment: @Benjamin Very true. I guess we'll have to wait to find out.